# inequality in statistics $P (ω : P (ω) ≤ \alpha) ≤ \alpha.$

Tags: statistics

We say that a random variable $E (ω)$ is an e-value if

$E [E] ≤ 1,$

and we say that a random variable $P (ω)$ is a p-value if for any $\alpha \in [0, 1]$:

$P (ω : P (ω) ≤ \alpha) ≤ \alpha.$

Prove that $P = \min \{1, 1/E\}$ is a p-value. The range of the e-value E is non-negative.

My attempt:

I am trying to prove $P (ω : \min \{1, 1/E(w)\} ≤ \alpha) ≤ \alpha.$

I can write $P (ω : \min \{1, 1/E(w)\}  ≤ \alpha) = 1 - P (ω : \min \{1, 1/E(w)\}  > \alpha)$

$= 1-P(1>\alpha, 1/E(w) > \alpha)$

In the first case, $\alpha =1$, then any probability is $\leq 1$, so the statement holds. In the second case,  $0 \leq \alpha <1$, we then have

$= 1-P(1>\alpha, 1/E(w) > \alpha)= 1-P( 1/E(w) > \alpha)$

Then I am stuck. I don't know how to use e-value condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1\geq E [E] \geq E[EI_{E \geq \frac 1 {\alpha}}] \geq \frac 1  {\alpha} P(E \geq \frac 1  {\alpha})$ so $P(E \geq \frac 1  {\alpha}) \leq \alpha$.  Finally, if $\alpha <1$ then $P(\min \{1,\frac 1  {E} \}\leq \alpha )) = P(E \geq \frac 1  {\alpha}) \leq \alpha$.

Comment: Is $E[E]=1$? or $E[E]\leq 1$

Comment: @Bey Thanks for the correction.

Comment: if $\alpha <1$ then $P(\min \{1,\frac 1  {E} \}\leq \alpha )) \leq P(E \geq \frac 1  {\alpha}).$ Can we change this $ \leq $ relation to = relation ?

Comment: @Jonathen Yes, we can.

Comment: Can you explain $E [E] \geq E[EI_{E \geq \frac 1 {\alpha}}] \geq \frac 1  {\alpha} P(E \geq \frac 1  {\alpha})$?

Comment: The first inequality is because $E$ is non-negative. The second one is because $EI_{E \geq 1/\alpha} \geq 1/\alpha I_{E \geq 1/\alpha}$ (Just take expectation on both sides).  @Jonathen

Comment: Can you explain why $EI_{E \geq 1/\alpha}    \geq  1/\alpha I_{E \geq 1/\alpha}$

Comment: @Jonathen Verify that the inequqlity is true in the two cases $E \geq 1/\alpha$ and $E <1/\alpha$.

Comment: Can you tell me what the meaning of your notation is $E[E I_{E \geq \frac{1}{\alpha}}]$

Comment: @Jonathen It is $E$ multiplied by the indicator function of the event $E\geq \frac 1 {\alpha}$.